# Linearly independence over C and over R

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $\{ix^2 +x -i, x^2-ix+1,x^2 -ix\}$ , Is it necessary linearly independent over C? over R?

Well, I did prove that it's necessary independent over C and over R but it's obviously wrong, I need your help to prove it right.

So I put it on a matrix like that:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        i & 1 & -1  \\
        1 & -i & 1  \\
        1 & -i & 0  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

And then I  got
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & -i & 1  \\
        0 & -1 & -i-1  \\
        0 & 0 & -1  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

And I explained that because they have complex variables inside the matrix and it's linearly independent then it's linearly independent over C, and because $ R \subset C $ then it's also true over R but I don't think that I can say that which means it won't be necessary independent over R at all. What do you guys think?

Comment: I'm confused by this statement. You are given a collection of polynomials and you are given that they are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$ and over $\Bbb R$. Then you are asked to prove that they are not necessarily independent over $\Bbb C$ or over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What does the first paragraph say?

Comment: Given $\{ix^2 +x -i, x^2-ix+1,x^2 -ix\}$ is linearly independent over C and over R. Can you show that it's not necessary linearly independent over C or over R?

Comment: I think that it's linearly independent over C but it's not over R, but I need to prove it. so I think I just did prove it over C because it has complex numbers in the matrix and it's also linearly independent so it's linearly independent over C, right? Then, what about R?

Comment: The way this question is written is somewhat of a contradiction. Basically this says "Given $X$ is true, prove $X$ is false." Are you sure this is the exact wording?

Comment: Edit: Given $\{ix^2 +x -i, x^2-ix+1,x^2 -ix\}$ , Is it necessary linearly independent over C? over R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this problem you are given a collection
$$
\beta=\{ix^2 +x -i, x^2-ix+1,x^2 -ix\}
$$
of polynomials in $\Bbb C[x]$. Note that $\Bbb C[x]$ can be considered as both an $\Bbb R$-vector space and a $\Bbb C$-vector space. You are asked if $\beta$ is independent over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

To see if $\beta$ is independent over a field $F$, suppose
$$
\lambda_1\cdot(ix^2 +x -i)+\lambda_2\cdot(x^2-ix+1)+\lambda_3\cdot(x^2 -ix)=\mathbf{0}\tag{1}
$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in F$ are not all zero. Note that (1) is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -i & -i \\
-i & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}
$$
But 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null
\begin{bmatrix}
i & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -i & -i \\
-i & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span_{\Bbb C}\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
i\\ -1\\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
so $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution to (2) if and only if
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}
=
\lambda\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
i\\ -1\\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$. This is possible if $F=\Bbb C$ but not possible if $F=\Bbb R$ (can you prove this?). Hence $\beta$ is independent over $\Bbb R$ but not independent over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Got it now, thanks!

Comment: how did you do elemntary row operations on the matrix to get to [i,-1,2] I did it and got that it was dependent, but I see you did with elementary column operations, but can you show it on rows?

Comment: Brian? Still didnt get your lamdas. Can you help pls?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13473/2014/5/26), if it helps.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks Martin!!!